# Why regex function not works using multiple values?

Tags: jquery, regex, string, function, split

I work on projects it works fine but when I add value color then it doesn't work?

here is my [Js Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/pikitemplates/rxacdnygu/), when we use **#color=(#333)** then it should change the color of the background button but it doesn't

same like in **#size=(1)** it adds a class in button but now **the code doesn't work**

I just add regex function and the code stopped working Please check the jsFiddle

here these lines of code stop working

```
var color = getAttr(info, "color");
var size = getAttr(info, "size");
```

While the rest of the code works fine, Any help or advice is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You regex seems wrong on the second-half

```
/(?:(\#[a-zA-Z]{4,})=\(([a-z A-Z]{4,})\))/g
```

This would indicates the string should have

1. hash `#`
2. letter-ONLY character (minimum 4 characters)
3. equal `=`
4. another letter-ONLY character (minimum 4 characters) in brackets

Thus, your example `#color=(#333)` not working bcoz it has hash `#` and `#size=(1)` not working bcoz it is not letter and only have 1 character.

**SOLUTION:**
You should use like this instead:

```
/(?:(\#[a-zA-Z]+)=\(([^\)]+)\))/g
```

Comment: **Not work I update in jsFiddle? please did you check properly in jsFiddle it's not working**

Comment: Maybe more like `/(?:(\#[a-zA-Z]{4,})=\(([^\)]+)\))/g`

Comment: Please tell me why **4 is used in regex**, i want to remove this 4 and make global

Comment: @riya875 we thought you are the one that put it there. If you dont want it, change it to plus `+` instead. I updated the answer.